# How do you reload the current route with route resolvers in Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-resolver

How do you reload the current route (with route resolvers) in Angular 11 without using `window.href` or `navigateByUrl`?
I just want to re-run the route resolvers.

Comment: is something like `/:id/` url param got changed when you "reload the route"?

Comment: @Andrei no. the /:id/ did not change. Just some other properties of the object currently being viewed.